# Grid view missplaced remove space between the grid view to other elements

Tags: xml, xamarin, android-gridview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0fSi.jpg)

can someone help i need that the grid view will take a place in the center between the add button to the top spinners i need him to capture all the white space in the middle and i dont know how to do it. 
the propble is that its starts the grid view on the top of the add button.
heres the code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:text="Welcome - "
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:gravity= "center"
            android:id="@+id/txtvHeadLine"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:text="Type"
            android:gravity="left"

        />
         <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:text="Brand"
            android:gravity="left"

        />
         <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:text="Color"
            android:gravity="left"

        />

     </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"> 

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:id="@+id/spnType"     
        />

       <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:id="@+id/spnBrand"     
       />
       <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:id="@+id/spnColor"     
       />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"  
            android:id="@+id/imgbtnSearch"
            android:src="@drawable/search"

        />
    </LinearLayout>
      <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
        android:numColumns="auto_fit" 
        android:id="@+id/GrdView"
    />
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:text="add"        
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

imgur.com/eBZjR.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to achieve the result like following sceenshot?

[image]

If so, you remove the `layout_weight` in your `LinearLayout`, just set the `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. Here is layout code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:text="Welcome - "
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:gravity= "center"
            android:id="@+id/txtvHeadLine"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:text="Type"
            android:gravity="left"

        />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:text="Brand"
            android:gravity="left"

        />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:text="Color"
            android:gravity="left"

        />
    </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="horizontal"> 

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:id="@+id/spnType"     
        />

       <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:id="@+id/spnBrand"     
       />
       <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:id="@+id/spnColor"     
       />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"  
            android:id="@+id/imgbtnSearch"
            android:src="@drawable/search"

        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:id="@+id/GrdView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="add"
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Update**

You have to set a specific height for the `GridView` to achieve it. Here is running screenshot.
[image]

Here is code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:text="Welcome - "
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:gravity= "center"
            android:id="@+id/txtvHeadLine"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:text="Type"
            android:gravity="left"

        />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:text="Brand"
            android:gravity="left"

        />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:text="Color"
            android:gravity="left"

        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:id="@+id/spnType"     
        />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:id="@+id/spnBrand"     
       />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:id="@+id/spnColor"     
       />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imgbtnSearch"
            android:src="@drawable/search"

        />
    </LinearLayout>

        <GridView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="400dp"
           android:numColumns="auto_fit"
           android:id="@+id/GrdView"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:gravity="center"
        />

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="add"

        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: allmost i want it to go down i mean to take the whole middle of the screen from bottom add button to the top

Comment: I update my answer, you can refer to it, Is that your needs? If the reply is helpful, please mark it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer ), it will help others who have similar issue